# Changing a dropdown menu's value AND display name to SQL query results based on a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, sql, forms, menu, drop-down-menu

Important note: **Most of the things I want from this are finished & functional -- the only part that doesn't work is getting a "value=" that is different from the name of the select option of the dropdown.** That said I'm going to lay this whole thing out for the benefit of anyone who might want to use something similar.

---

**Goal:** When the user clicks a radio button, a dropdown menu elsewhere on the page is modified to show different values, which are drawn from an SQL query.

Specifically in this example, a user would pick an academic program (say, a Ph.D.) and the dropdown shows which start dates are available.

Here is an SQL query which gets the available start dates, and formats them for the Javascript:

```
$app_period_lookup_psyd =  mssql_query("select app_period_id,
app_period_display_online from  dbo.v_app001_application_period_for_dropdown 
where pgm_id = 1 order by available_dt");
$app_period_options_psyd = "";
while($result = mssql_fetch_array($app_period_lookup_psyd)) {
$app_period_options_psyd .= "'" . $result['app_period_display_online'] ."', ";
}
```

The variable created here is **$app_period_options_psyd**, and it would spit out something like:
**'September 2011', 'January 2012',**

These are the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="pgm_id" id="macpe" value="4"
onclick="change([<?=$app_period_options_psyd?>]) " />Radio Button 1<br />

<input type="radio" name="pgm_id" id="macpd" value="5"
onclick="change(['January', 'February', 'March']) " />Radio Button 2
```

Clicking these two buttons would generate the following dropdowns:

```
<select id="app_period_id">
<option value="September 2011">September 2011</option>
<option value="January 2012">January 2012</option>
</select>

<select id="app_period_id">
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
</select>
```

They work via this script in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(arr) {
    var el = document.getElementById('app_period_id');
    el.options.length = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++ ) {
    el.options[el.options.length] = new Option( arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
    }
</script>
```

**THE QUESTION:** How do I modify the Javascript to create different values for value="" and the descriptor, with BOTH values coming from the query/queries? This is the ideal output:

```
<select id="app_period_id">
<option value="app_period_1">January 2012</option>
<option value="app_period_6">February 2012</option>
<option value="app period_18">March 2013</option>
</select>
```

Where "app_period_x" would be generated in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

```
$app_period_options_psyd .= "'" . $result['app_period_display_online'] ."', ";
```

becomes

```
$app_period_options_psyd .= "'" . $results['app_period_id'] . "'," . $result['app_period_display_online'] ."', ";
```

This means your array now looks like

arr_[0] = Id
arr_[1] = Name associated
etc.

Now change the Javascript function to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(arr) {
    var el = document.getElementById('app_period_id');
    el.options.length = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i+=2 ) {
    el.options[el.options.length] = new Option( arr[i], arr[i+1]);
    }
    }
</script>
```

You are now looping through the array two steps, and putting out both elements into your code.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to be outputting that data. I've tried a few different things, and fixed one error ( $results should be $result ). I'm still testing to see if the form is outputting those two things. I definitely see the logic in the reply, though.

I'll be sure to let you know if I manage it (or not) in the next few days.